# zfs mirror /home partition only?

Tags: partitioning, zfs

I've just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04 and would like to know if it's reasonably possible to ZFS-mirror a pair of PARTITIONS on two matching SSDs to accommodate my /home directory only.

I've googled around and have found only a few hints suggesting it's possible to create mirrored ZFS on disc partitions rather than whole discs but have discovered no explicit commentary about how to implement that solution. It's always about pooling entire discs.

Until some future Ubuntu release provides a native-install option for ZFS, it would be enough that I could merely mirror partitions for greater data integrity for irreplaceable contents which matter most to me -- without facing what appears to be a fairly complex hat dance to manually install the entire root system on ZFS.

That would also take me to a level of bleeding-edginess which I tend to avoid since I'm more a business user than a geek. Which is to say I use technology but don't adore it.

Can anyone point to some reference out there on this subject which I've not yet found? Or else offer some explicit hints about how to implement a partitions-only zfs solution?

Thanks!

ADDED: It appears what I was looking for is well documented in the FreeBSD Handbook references to ZFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly possible although not very efficient as the disk head will seek between both disk areas for all writes.

ZFS allows to work with whole disks, primary and logical partitions and files.

Note that ZFS also support multiple data copies to help overcoming bit rot:

```
zfs set copies=2 dataset
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do remember, however, that this is a laptop business machine, not a server.  The need for efficiency is trumped by the need for accurate archiving of business information, most of which rarely or never changes (apart from coming and going of email). I did convert my /home partition to a ZFS pool and I see no difference in response time.

Comment: On further consideration of your reply, I don't really see how read/write time would be different to using any other mirrored file system, given the two zfs mirror partitions are located on two different discs -- not two partitions located on the same disc.  I did, however, take your suggestion to set copies=2 since I have vastly more space available on that partition than I could ever possibly fill up.